# How to mock a Es6 class using Jest?

Tags: typescript, jestjs, mocking

I am trying the mock a class using jest.mock with factory parameter. However, it does not seem to work as expected.

I got the error "**TypeError: projectSettings.getProjectDir is not a function**".

I think I have followed the documentation properly, however could missing something basic. https://jestjs.io/docs/en/es6-class-mocks. Could you please tell me what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

It works perfectly when I do

```
  const projectSettings = {
    getProjectDir: jest.fn(),
    setProjectDir: jest.fn()
  };
```

Does not work:

```
const projectSettings = jest.mock('./projectSettings',()=>{
  return function() {
    return {
        getProjectDir: jest.fn(),
        setProjectDir: jest.fn()
    }
  }
});
```

test

```
 test('Set Project Directory Menu click should open dialog', async () => {
    const setDirMenuItem = subMenu.getSetProjectDirSubMenu(
      <any>mainWindow,
      <any>projectSettings
    );
    await setDirMenuItem.click();
    expect(dialog.showOpenDialog).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Code under test

```
export const getSetProjectDirSubMenu = (
  mainWindow: BrowserWindow,
  projectSettings: ProjectSettings
) => ({
  label: 'Set Project Directory',
  click: async () => {
    const result = await dialog.showOpenDialog(mainWindow, {
      properties: ['openDirectory'],
      defaultPath: projectSettings.getProjectDir()
    });

    if (result.filePaths[0]) {
      projectSettings.setProjectDir(result.filePaths[0]);
      mainWindow.webContents.send('PROJECT_DIRECTORY_SET', {});
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Why don't you continue to use the thing that works? You don't need to mock parameters via the module system, and the code you're testing has no idea whether it's a class instance or a vanilla object.

Comment: Thanks @jonrsharpe. you are correct. I should use what works. I was trying to better understand how the jest.mock() method work. However, my approach may be incorrect.